# is shell_exec() sub-process supposed to inherit euid?

Tags: php, linux, posix, uid

i'm running php-cli 7.3.19 as root (on a Debian 10 Buster, linux kernel 4.19.0-8-amd64), and after using posix_seteuid() to change my euid, is sub-processes supposed to inherit my euid?

i thought the answer was yes, but testing it,

```
root@devdb:/srv/http/easyad_branches# whoami
root
root@devdb:/srv/http/easyad_branches# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@devdb:/srv/http/easyad_branches# php -r ' \
var_dump(posix_seteuid(posix_getpwnam("www-data")["uid"])); \
var_dump(shell_exec("whoami;id")); \ 
posix_seteuid(0); \
var_dump(posix_setuid(posix_getpwnam("www-data")["uid"])); \ 
var_dump(shell_exec("whoami;id"));'
bool(true)
string(44) "root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
"
bool(true)
string(53) "www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
"
```

it seems whoami inherits my *uid* as it's *euid*, rather than inheriting my *euid* as it's *euid*, is that intended behavior?

to say it in another way, i got `bool(true) root bool(true) www-data` , but i expected `bool(true) www-data bool(true) www-data` , is my expectations wrong, or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems whoami inherits my uid as it's euid, rather than inheriting my euid as it's euid, is that intended behavior?

I'm not 100% sure about PHP, but in programming languages directly calling Linux system calls (such as C or C++) this behavior is normal.

One well-known side-effect of this behavior is that setting the `set-euid` bit to a shell script makes no sense (as long as the "normal" shell - e.g. bash - is used):

The shell (e.g. `/bin/sh`) would be started with `euid` set to a different UID, but the programs started by the shell would have both `euid` and `uid` set to the `uid` value of the shell, which is the UID of the user that started the script...